# How can I iterate over the elements in Hashmap?

Tags: java

I want to make a Java game. At first the program asks for the number of the players; after that, it asks for their names. I put their names in a `HashMap` with an ID and their score. At the end of the game I count the score and I want to put it in the `HashMap` (the specific score for the specific name). Does anyone know how to do this? This is my code:

**Player:**

```
public class Player {

public Player() {
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private String name;
private int score;

public Player(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
 public String getName() { 
     return name;
 }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player{" + "name=" + name + "score=" + score + '}';
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
```

**main:**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<Integer,Player> name= new HashMap<Integer,Player>();

    System.out.printf("Give the number of the players ");
    int number_of_players = scanner.nextInt();


    for(int k=1;k<=number_of_players;k++)
     {


         System.out.printf("Give the name of player %d: ",k);
         name_of_players= scanner.nextLine();
         name.put(k, new Player(name_of_players,0));//k=id and 0=score

     }


   //This for finally returns the score and          
    for(int k=1;k<=number_of_players;k++)
  {  
      Player name1 = name.get(k);
     System.out.print("Name of player in this round:"+name1.getName());
    ..............
    .............
    int score=p.getScore();
    name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr));//I think here is the problem

    for(int n=1;n<=number_of_players;n++)//prints all the players with their score
      {

     System.out.print("The player"+name1.getName()+" has "+name1.getScore()+"points");

      }
```

Does anyone know how can I finally print for example:

```
"The player Nick has 10 points.
 The player Mary has 0 points."
```

**Update:**

I did this in main(as Jigar Joshi suggest)

```
 name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr)); 
 Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Player>> set =   name.entrySet();

 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Player> me : set) 
 { 
 System.out.println("Score :"+me.getValue().getScore() +" Name:"+me.getValue().getName()); 

}
```

and it prints "Score :0 Name : a Score :4 Name : a" when i put two names of players "a" and "b".I think the problem is here

```
 name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr));
```

How can I put the names in "names_of_players" of my previous `for`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Need Key & Value in Iteration

Use [`entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) to iterate through `Map` and need to access value and key:

```
Map<String, Person> hm = new HashMap<String, Person>();

hm.put("A", new Person("p1"));
hm.put("B", new Person("p2"));
hm.put("C", new Person("p3"));
hm.put("D", new Person("p4"));
hm.put("E", new Person("p5"));

Set<Map.Entry<String, Person>> set = hm.entrySet();

for (Map.Entry<String, Person> me : set) {
  System.out.println("Key :"+me.getKey() +" Name : "+ me.getValue().getName()+"Age :"+me.getValue().getAge());

}
```

## Need Key in Iteration

If you want just to iterate over `keys` of map you can use [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29)

```
for(String key: map.keySet()) {
     Person value = map.get(key); 
}
```

## Need Value in Iteration

If you just want to iterate over `values` of map you can use [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29)

```
for(Person person: map.values()) {

}
```

Comment: +1 entrySet() is reasonable if you need both key and value. Also you can iterate directly over values (or keys) only.

Comment: thanks for your answer!i think i'm very close to the answer. i wrote this as you said [code]name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr));
 Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Player>> set = name.entrySet();
                    
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Player> me : set) {
  System.out.println("Score :"+me.getValue().getScore() +" Name : "+ me.getValue().getName());
}[/code] and it prints "Score :0 Name : a
Score :4 Name : a" when i put two names of players "a" and "b".I think the problem is here "name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr));" How can i put the names in  "names_of_players" of my previous for?

Comment: please update your question and then comment here to point to the update

Comment: Didn't understand your update. may be you can open a new post if your current issue was solved and if you have new issue

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.Secondly,the issue is that in the  first for i get the names of the players and in the last for,when i count the score,i cant put those names in the map with the specific score.I hope now you understand.

Comment: What do you mean by _ and in the last for,when i count the score,i cant put those names in the map with the specific score_

Comment: The purpose of the last for is to count the score and print :"The player Nick has 10 points.
The player Mary has 0 points."The update prints:"The player Nick has 10 points.The player Nick has 0 points."So,i cant get the name of "Mary" with her score.(The score of Mary remains to Nick)

Comment: and for that reason i think the problem is in " name.put(k,new Player(name1.getName(),scr));"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6199/discussion-between-jigar-joshi-and-des)

Answer (score 3):

You should not map score to player. You should map player (or his name) to score:

`Map<Player, Integer> player2score = new HashMap<Player, Integer>();`

Then add players to map:
int score = ....
Player player = new Player();
player.setName("John");
// etc.
player2score.put(player, score);

In this case the task is trivial:

`int score = player2score.get(player);`

Answer (score 3):

Since all the players are numbered I would just use an `ArrayList<Player>()`

Something like

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

System.out.printf("Give the number of the players ");
int number_of_players = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // discard the rest of the line.

for(int k = 0;k < number_of_players; k++){
     System.out.printf("Give the name of player %d: ", k + 1);
     String name_of_player = scanner.nextLine();
     players.add(new Player(name_of_player,0)); //k=id and 0=score
}

for(Player player: players) {  
    System.out.println("Name of player in this round:" + player.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Integer,Player> hash = new HashMap<Integer,Player>();
Set keys = hash.keySet();   
Iterator itr = keys.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
    Integer key = itr.next();
    Player objPlayer = (Player) hash.get(key);
    System.out.println("The player "+objPlayer.getName()+" has "+objPlayer.getScore()+" points");
}
```

You can use this code to print all scores in your format.