# How can i print this right?

Tags: java

This simple program asks for the number of players,their names and (in the last for) it counts their score.But I dont know why it doen't go to the next player.Look at my code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String,Integer> players= new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    System.out.printf("Give the number of the players: ");
    int numOfPlayers = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int k=1;k<=numOfPlayers;k++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Give the name of player %d: ",k);
        String nameOfPlayer= scanner.next();
        players.put(nameOfPlayer,0);//score=0
    }

    //This for finally returns the score 
    for(String name:players.keySet())
    { 
      int k=1;
      do{ 
          System.out.println("Name of player in this round: "+name);
           System.out.printf("Give me your word: ");
           String nameOfWord= scanner.next();

          //::::::::::::::::::::::
          //::::::::::::::::::::::

          int score=players.get(name)+10;
          //This will update the corresponding entry in HashMap
          players.put(name,score);
          System.out.println("The Player "+name+" has "+players.get(name)+" points ");
    }while(k>0);
}
}  }
```

This returns:

```
 Give the number of the players: 2
 Give the name of player 1: A
 Give the name of player 2: B
 Name of player in this round: A
 Give me your word: ABC
 The Player A has 10 points 
 Name of player in this round: A
 Give me your word:......
........
```

but i want after it counts the score for 'A' to count the score for 'B'.How can i do this?What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think you already got the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644176/how-can-i-add-elements-in-hashmap/8644194#8644194

Comment: Look at your `k` variable! You set it to 1 and then have `do { ... } while (k > 0);` <-- the condition is always true, you never cycle through the second entry (unless you decrement k in the missing code)

Comment: @JigarJoshi without the do-while it works but now i have to include them it doesnt..

Comment: what do you mean by "but now i have to include them it doesnt"? include who/what where?

Comment: i mean that at fisrt i had only the for loop..but know i wrote some more code in my program and they are necessary..

Comment: if you're convinced you need that loop, then you'd also have to change the `k` variable somewhere - or you get a neverending loop! it's as simple as that.

Comment: please update your question with what you actually want to achieve in the "main loop" of your game, apart from switching from player to player (which works if you remove the while loop).

Comment: @nyarlathotep without do-while it stops after counting the score if the second player...so the fisrt one cant play again...i want what excactly you said "switching from player to player"

Comment: see my answer: You probably want the `do...while` loop around the `for ...` loop, not the other way round as you currently have it. additionally, you'd have to change the `k` variable somewhere - what is the condition for the game to be over? Please update your question instead of commenting on each and every answer here... that would be much easier (and less redundant)

Comment: thaaaaanks maybe it was simplier than i thougth!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change the variable `k` anywhere in your `do ... while` loop (which is the only variable contained in the loop condition) - meaning that it will loop forever with the first player!

If I'm interpreting correctly what you want to do, you should completely remove the `do {` and the `} while (k>0)` lines - you don't even reference the value of `k` anywhere inside the loop, except for in the condition; is it maybe a remainder of iterating over the players in another way?

Or, if it should have been the loop for the doing the game rounds (one round being the collection of one turn for each player), then it's in the wrong position - it should be around the `for ...` loop iterating over the players, not inside it; you'd of course also have to come up with a proper condition for the game to be over - if it really depends on the `k` variable you're currently using, then this variable would also have to change somwhere, or your back to a neverending loop!

But it's hard to interpret your code without more information; please update your question with more information on how a full round should look like in your game, and what the condition is that the game is over!

Comment: i use the do-while so the players play one after another until they  game ends-then k=0 and i will continue outside the do-while...thats my thought...

Comment: @nick: doesn't make sense to me - what would you need it for? as it is at the moment, the only thing it is doing is creating a neverending loop!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `do while` - you don't need it.  Also, iterate "properly" over the `Map`.
Here's the re-worked code fragment:

```
// Note this more elegant iteration over a map
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : players.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    int score = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Name of player in this round: " + name);
    System.out.printf("Give me your word: ");
    String nameOfWord = scanner.next();
    // Some code that uses "nameOfWord"
    score += 10;
    entry.setValue(score); // Note this more elegant use of the API
    System.out.println("The Player " + name + " has " + score + " points");
}
```

I must admit I don't understand what you're trying to do, but at least this code does what your code intended.

Comment: thanks for your answer!this stops after counting the score for the second player...but i want to play again the fisrt player,count his score,after play again the second etc....how can i do this?(thats why i wanted to use do-while).

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using do-while.I see no use of it.And ofcourse that is causing the problem as you are never increasing k and it seems to be infinte loop to me

Comment: i use the do-while so the players play one after another until they game ends-then k=0 and i will continue outside the do-while...thats my thought...